Help adding Nvidia 32-bit driver in order to run Steam
When I launched Steam for the first time, it indicated I needed to install Nvidia 32-bit drivers alongside my 64-bit driver for it to work correctly. It advised that I try the following code in order to do that:
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-<YOUR_DRIVER_VERSION>:i386

I ran nvidia-smi to confirm that my driver version is 535.183.01 and then attempted to install i386 as shown in the third step of the above code and kept getting bash: 535.183.01: no such file or directory.
I'm assuming that I'm entering in the driver version in the command line incorrectly? Below is what I tried:
sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-<535.183.01>:i386

Where am I going wrong?
I am very new to Linux btw and couldn't find the answer to this Googling. Advice would be very appreciated.
EDIT: I am running Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop.

Apologies, I will update my post to reflect this information: I am running Ubuntu 24.04 LTS desktop

Can you also try that command without "< >" symbols?

sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-535:i386

@osbm that worked, thank you a bunch!
